# Knockout custom binding for FullCalendar v4, dependent on dropdown selection

Tags: knockout.js, dropdown, fullcalendar-4

I recently asked for help creating a knockout custom binding for FullCalendar V4. Now I'm trying to make it dependent on a dropdown selected value. I'm trying to get the calendar to bind the events, based on the dropdown selection. Please view the linked [pen](https://codepen.io/jjfrick/pen/mdyPmev). Here's what I have for the binding so far...

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fullCalendar = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            console.log("value: ", value)
            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(element, {
                plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ],
                defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
                defaultDate: '2019-06-07',
                header: {
                  left: 'prev,next today',
                  center: 'title',
                  right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
                },
                //events: viewModel.array1()
                events: viewModel.selectedChoice(value)
            });
            calendar.render(); 
        },
        update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            console.log(value)
            if (value === "array1"){
                events: viewModel.array1();
            } else {
                events: viewModel.array2();
            }
        }
};
```

Comment: So... what's the question? Is the binding working or does it not do something right?

Comment: Jason - I edit the above text. Please view the pen. I'm trying to show events based on the dropdown selection.

Comment: Ok but... "I'm trying" isn't a **question**, or a description of a **problem**. What happens when you try? What goes wrong? What did you expect to happen? Where are you stuck? It's a bit unclear precisely what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like FullCalendar has the ability to pull events from a function so you should be able to use something like your getEvents function in the initialize portion (`events: viewModel.getEvents`). Then all you need to do in the update portion of the binding is call your calendar's `refetchEvents` method and it will refresh using the new values that your function returns. Build your switch based on the observable's value into the function and spit out the correct values there.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function